# HttpListenerContext.AcceptWebSocketAsync error 1229

Tags: websocket

I'm trying to add a WebSocket to existing code which handles HTTP requests. Not using IIS or ASP.NET, just C# code with an HttpListener. When the client sends the upgrade request, the server bombs:

```
System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException was unhandled by user code
  ErrorCode=1229
  HResult=-2147467259
  Message=An error occurred when sending the WebSocket HTTP upgrade response during the AcceptWebSocketAsync operation. The HRESULT returned is '1229'
  NativeErrorCode=1229
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHelpers.<AcceptWebSocketAsyncCore>d__17.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at mycode.<mymethod>d__46.MoveNext() 
  InnerException:
```

Calling code:

```
HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
if (context.Request.IsWebSocketRequest)
{
    HttpListenerWebSocketContext wsContext = await context.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null);
```

I find the MS documentation on the entire WebSockets namespace to be useless with no code examples. I don't know what it's trying to tell me here (other than the obvious fact that I'm not handling the exception - I want to know why there is an exception in the first place).

This is Windows 10, .NET framework 4.5. I have noticed places in the documentation which say that WebSockets only works with Windows 8 and 2012, but I assume it should work with 10 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to go to Windows Features, under IIS (even though I'm not using IIS), and turn on WebSocket Protocol. I don't know whether this being off is Win10 default or just due to the image IT installed for me.